# Redistribute dictionary value lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, dictionary

I have the following dict:

```
groups = {"group 1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
          "group 2": [5, 6, 7, 8],
          "group 3": [9, 10, 11, 12],
          "group 4": [13, 14]}
```

When the length of a group is smaller than a minimum size (`group_size=4`), I want to redistribute the members to the other groups. The result in this case would be something like:

```
groups = {"group 1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 13],
          "group 2": [5, 6, 7, 8, 14],
          "group 3": [9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

I have the following code, which works, but is less efficient than I'd like:

```
# Identify small groups
small_groups = []
for group_name, group_members in groups.items():
    if len(group_members) < group_size:
        small_groups.append(group_name)

# Redistribute members of small groups to the larger groups
to_redistribute = []
for group_name in small_groups:
    to_redistribute.extend(groups.pop(group_name))

for group_name, group_members in groups.items():
    if not to_redistribute:
        break
    group_members.append(to_redistribute.pop())
```

Important note: The real members of groups are strings, not integers.

Is there a better way to redistribute dictionary value lists?

Comment: what if there are only 5 numbers, i mean group size is less than 4 and the total value counts are only 5

Comment: Why is it inefficient?

Comment: Sorry bout that, fixed and edited my answer.

Comment: If the minimum_size is huge compared to the number of groups, you could probably make this much more efficient by grouping the values to be distributed into chunks (like dealing cards a hand at a time instead of a card at a time). But if it's going to be around the same size, as in your example, that's more likely to slow things down than speed them up.

Comment: @Kalyan - the group_size is actually set based I am dividing people into quartiles and making groups from 1 person per quartile. However, because I won't necessarily have multiples of four in number of people, not all the groups might be of size 4. In the event that there are less than 4 people, there's logic elsewhere to handle that.

Comment: @johnashu I just was hoping there's a better way than looping through multiple times. While this specific example doesn't have real efficiency problems, I was hoping to be able to generalize a process where it might be more important.

Comment: Your question says your approach "is less efficient than I'd like", so I assumed you had a real efficiency problem with your real data. If you do, that same problem may well apply to Coldspeed's answer—so you should explain the size and shape of your data and why it's too slow, so we can tell you whether that answer is good enough or provide something more complicated but faster if necessary.

Comment: Your title is misleading, we don't care about values or what's in the groups, only their lengths. How about *"Given dict-of-dicts, redistribute groups shorter than threshold by appending them to the others"*. "dict-of-dicts" is clearer than "dictionary value lists".

Comment: Do you care about evenly handling corner cases with multiple short groups sprinkled in, say group lengths 4,4,2,4,3,2,1? Do the group lengths need to be evenly-matched in that case? Does the order in which the too-short groups get redistributed matter? (original order/longest-group-first/arbitrary?) A solution might need to be recursive.

Comment: I’m open to changing the name, but it’s not a dict of dicts and that’s also a very long title

Comment: ZaxR: ok please propose a name. I should have said "dict-of-lists". I can't understand *"dictionary value lists"*, and it doesn't really describe your use case. There's no need to say "list of values" if you merely mean "lists". As to title length, in those cases where a title needs to be long to clearly state the question, IMO that's preferable than something short and ambiguous that will get confused by SO search, duplicates, Google etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is good, but you can combine the pop and re-distribution logic together using `itertools.cycle`.

```
from itertools import cycle

for k in list(groups.keys()):
    if len(groups[k]) < group_size:
        for v, k_ in zip(groups.pop(k), cycle(groups.keys())):
            groups[k_].append(v)
```

The idea is to keep cycling through keys to re-distribute the data equally. It determines—at each iteration—whether a group is over the threshold or not. If a group is valid, then augmenting it later (via re-distribution) will *never* bring it *under* the threshold. However groups that are initially under the threshold (but are not reached until later during future iterations) can possibly become valid if and when you augment values to it from another group that was removed. If that does not happen, then it will be removed and its data redistributed on a future iteration.

Keep in mind, groups that were initially slated for removal *may now become valid* after redistribution, so our solutions will differ in the output for some inputs.

```
print(groups)
{'group 1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 13],
 'group 2': [5, 6, 7, 8, 14],
 'group 3': [9, 10, 11, 12]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'll take a closer look at cycle - but this doesn't quite get what I need. In the event that all the groups can't be of equal size, I need the smaller groups to be distributed among the larger ones (13 and 14 are missing in your answer b/c of zip I'm guessing). Any way to modify this type of solution for that?

Comment: @ZaxR Sorry, the 13 and 14 missing was a typo, it works just fine.

Comment: @ZaxR So what this does, is it determines on the fly whether a group is too small. If a group is big enough, then adding more to it (via re-distribution) will never make it too small. However groups that are initially too small can possibly become valid after augmenting values to it from another group. If not, then it will be redistributed again on a future iteration.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer and explanation!

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `filter` and `sum` to pull out concatenated lists with lengths less than `4`
2. Use comprehension to rebuild new dictionary with lists whose lengths are greater than or equal to `4`
3. iterative remove one item from the filtered list and append it to the newly built dictionary key until all items from filtered list are exhausted.

---

```
from itertools import cycle

f = lambda v: len(v) < 4
x = sum(filter(f, groups.values()), [])
g = {k: v for k, v in groups.items() if not f(v)}

c = cycle(g)
while x:
    g[next(c)].append(x.pop())

g

{'group 1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 14],
 'group 2': [5, 6, 7, 8, 13],
 'group 3': [9, 10, 11, 12]}
```